# XSS HTTP parameter pollution and getQueryString()

Tags: jsp, security, xss

I'm dealing with xss issues and found a problem I don't know how to solve it.

I've a report from Acunetx saying:

```
Details

POST (multipart) input query was set to idMenu=14&n907758=v929899
Parameter precedence: first occurrence
Affected link:
/MYAPP/jspfs/plantilla.jsp?idMenu=14&n907758=v929899&int1=-1&accion1=edit

Affected parameter: idMenu=14
```

In my jsp I've something like this:

```
          <input type="hidden" name="query" value="<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(request.getQueryString())%>" />

            <script>
              $(document).ready(function () {                    

                function send() {

                    location.href="<%=Utils.getParameter("ruta0") + "jspfs/plantillasTickets/plantillasTickets.jsp"%><%=query%>&idMenu=<%=idMenu%>&idioma="+valIdioma+"&grupo="+valGrupo;
                }
            </script>/>
```

So, the `getQueryString()` method used to mount the url is getting the value `idMenu=14&n907758=v929899&int1=-1&accion1=edit` which is interpreted as a new param `n907758`.

NOTE: To solve other xss issues, I'm using a filter where I canonize the request values, but in this case I've no clue how to distinguish the proper params of the injected one.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: You should output encode rather than input sanitize. Check out the [OWASP guide on XSS prevention](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: Actually I'm already doing it, but thanks anyway

Comment: Well in your code I can see that `query` is not JS hex encoded on output so that might be your problem (I don't know if you've processed that variable further up though of course).

Comment: You also need to parse `query` into name value pairs (say into a dictionary object) and add the new parameters to the dictionary. Then you can check that your code set parameters override any in the user set query string. Remember to percent encode on output and if putting into Javascript like above, remember to hex entity encode (`\x00`) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solve the Acunetix attack with this changues in the code. Hope it can help someone to deal with this kind of problems.

```
        <%-- the imput query has been deleted --%>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {                    

            function send() {

                <%
                    query = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(request.getQueryString());

                %>
                location.href="<%=Utils.getParameter("ruta0") + "jspfs/plantillasTickets/plantillasTickets.jsp" + query%>&idMenu=<%=idMenu%>&idioma="+valIdioma+"&grupo="+valGrupo;
            }
        </script>/>
```